# Style React-Native via Styles.xml

Tags: android, react-native

I am Building a React-Native Android application and I want to use the Android `Styles.xml` code in my React-Native Code. Is there a way to access these styles and override these styles on selected React-Native Components? Is there a way to access these Android Native XML styles in my React-Native Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I think this is a very bad idea because you are actually overriding the very same feature of RN, I guess you could create a Native Module in Android that exposes the Styles.XML in a CSS StyleSheet fashion and use that to style your components.

Again, it would be better to understand why you want to do this because you would need to create a process to transform XML to CSS.